# Angular - Access elementRef of MatMenu

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following setup:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[test]'
})
export class Test {
    constructor(
        private hostRef: ElementRef,
        private host: MatMenuTrigger,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.host.menuOpened.subscribe(() => {
            /* Do something with the MatMenu elementRef */
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<a [matMenuTriggerFor]="aMenu" test></a>
<mat-menu #aMenu></mat-menu>
```

I want to get the ElementRef of the MatMenu (not a reference to the opened MatMenu component nor the elementRef of the MatMenuTrigger).
After looking at the typescript definition file for the MatMenu class, I came across the `_elementRef` private property which allows me to access the elementRef like so:

```js
this.host.menuOpened.subscribe(() => {
    const ref = (this.host.menu as any)._elementRef;
    /* Do something with ref */
});
```

The only problem is that this is relying on the Angular team maintining this property in the future versions (and, well, the fact that this is a private property to begin with).

I could put the `test` directive directly on the `mat-menu` template, which would allow me to access its elementRef using the `ElementRef` injector, but I would loose access to the MatMenuTrigger functions such as `openMenu` and `closeMenu` (a MatMenu instance does not hold any reference to any of its associated MatMenuTrigger).

Is there a way to access the ElementRef of a MatMenu without using its private properties (or a way to close a MatMenu without having access to an associated MatMenuTrigger) ?
I need the ElementRef to test whether a click on the `document` came from the Menu (by testing if the menu elementRef is included inside the event [composedPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath))

Comment: will `@ViewChild(MatMenu, {read: ElementRef})` work for you?

Comment: This doesn't work because the MatMenu is not a child of the MatMenuTrigger. I could use this in the host component (as in the component which hosts both the trigger and the menu template) but I am trying to put everything inside the directive (so that it can be reused by other components).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're trying to pass the reference to the `mat-menu` element to your `test` Directive. If that's the case, try adding an `Input()` to the Directive:

```js
@Input() menu: MatMenu;
```

Then in your template:

```html
<a [matMenuTriggerFor]="aMenu" test [menuRef]="aMenu"></a>
<mat-menu #aMenu></mat-menu>
```

That way, you pass the component via local reference to your Directive.

Comment: While this does allow me to get a reference to the MatMenu component instance this does not solve my problem: I am looking for the ElementRef of the MatMenu, not the MatMenu itself (and @Input does not support the read metadata property, to I can't get the elementref this way)